# Is 'media' a reserved keyword in Android browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, android

I had a hard time debugging a javascript that worked fine in Firefox and Chromium, but not in Android browser.

Finally, I realized that the problem happened because I was using a variable called `media` (the Portuguese word for `average`).

After changing `media` to `media_calculada`, the problem was gone.

Checkout this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function debug(msg) {
                $('#debug').val($('#debug').val() + '\n' + msg);
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){
                media = 'simple string';
                othervar = 'simple string';
                debug(media);
                debug(othervar);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<textarea id="debug"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

That sample page results in the following output for each browser:

Ubuntu Firefox:

```
simple string
simple string
```

Android Firefox:

```
simple string
simple string
```

Android 2.3.7 native browser:

```
[ object Media ]
simple string
```

You can clearly see that the problem only happens in Android native browser.

I googled to see if I could find any information about that, but I didn't. (mainly because media is such a widely used word).

So, my question:

Is `media` a reserved keyword in Android browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed your problem. What you're actually seeing is the media property of the global object.

When you try to access a certain variable (e.g. `media`) JavaScript will look up the scope chain, trying to find a declaration for it. If it doesn't find one, it will *try* to create a property on the global object.

However, there is no guarantee that such a property is writable. Apparently, in your case, the `media` property of the global object isn't.

What you should be doing is declaring your variables:

```
var media = 'simple string';
var othervar = 'simple string';
```

If media was a reserved keyword, you would get a syntax error. Reserved keywords cannot be used as identifiers(e.g. as variable names, function names, and a bunch of other things).

Comment: Awesome analysis! You're right! If I try `debug(window.media)` I get the [ object Media ]. If I use a local variable or use document.media it then works fine!
Still, I haven't found any documentation about this window.media object of Android browser! If ever I found some, I'll update this question!
Thanks for your help!